# How can I make my website run a large C program on my server and return the output to the client?

Tags: php, wamp, windows-scripting

I would like to be able to take user input, run a program on my server based on that input, and return the output to the client in the form of a file. I don't know how to go about doing this. If I'm using a WAMP solution stack, do I need to have a function in my PHP code call a windows script and have that handle the interaction with my program? Is that the best way to go about this? Is that even possible?

Comment: Functions like `shell_exec()` and `exec()` will allow you to execute command line calls like you would do manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is a good framework for what you are trying to do

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=savethis.txt");

$command = null;
switch($_GET["input"])
{
    case "list":
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === "WIN") 
        {
            $command = "dir";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $command = "ls";
        }
    default:
    // do nothing 
    break;
}

if (!is_null($command))
{
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
}
```